# First jQuery plugin, am I on the right track?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So i assume this should be pretty simple... its just a custom Checkbox plugin that takes div's and turns them into checkboxes using css. All i really need it to do is basically swap css and trigger events. I only see need for these actions (init, check, uncheck, toggle, disable).
Any way heres what i have so far, but im stuck on the toggle method and the last part in general...

```
(function ($) {
    var method = {
        init: function () {
            $(this).addClass('cb-unchecked');
            $(this).click(//Should call toggle method, but unsure syntax);
        },

        check: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cb-disabled cb-unchecked').addClass('cb-checked').trigger('checked', this);
            });
        },

        uncheck: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cb-disabled cb-checked').addClass('cb-checked').trigger('unchecked', this);
            });
        },

        toggle: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (t.hasClass('cb-checked')) { //Should call the check function, but i dont know how...  }
                else if (t.hasClass('cb-unchecked')) { //Should call the uncheck function, but i dont know how...}
            });
        },

        disable: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cb-checked cb-unchecked').addClass('cb-disabled').trigger('disabled', this);
            });
        }

    };
    $.fn.customCheckbox = function (action) {

        //Im slightly lost at what would go here
        //if(method[action]){ method[action].apply(this, arguments);  }//????

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Am i headed in the right direction or should i be going about this completely differently?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - but unfortunately it seems to be too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. You wrapped it in (function($){..})(jQuery) to let jQuery play nicely with other javascript libraries. You maintain chainability by `return this;`. You properly extend jQuery by using `$.fn.customCheckbox = ...`. You can do as your comment says by applying the parameters to the function. Finally, just call it.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").customCheckbox('init');
```

although i would probably move the init code into the body of `$.fn.customCheckbox = function (action) {...}` when `!action`

```
$.fn.customCheckbox = function (action) {
        if(!action){
            // init here
        }
        // other logic here
        return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your comment is almost correct.
However, you need to remove the first argument (`action`) before calling the method:

```
method[action].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

You would call plugin methods the same way everyone else does:

```
this.customCheckbox("check");
```

Comment: ummm wouldn't you do `$(this).customCheckbox("check");`?

Comment: @Neal: Only inside an `each`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$.fn.customCheckbox = function (action) {
        if(action && method[action]){ 
           var args = arguments;
           args = $(args).slice(1);
           method[action].apply(this, args);  
        }
        return this;
}
```

Comment: `arguments` isn't an array and doesn't have a `slice` method.

Comment: @Slaks - Yes you are right, now is that fine?

Comment: Not really.  That might work, but it's misusing jQuery,

Comment: I tried in an example it works fine.